# Returning Entire Sub-Array (Containing Maximum Value) From Array

Tags: php

Trying to return the array where the key "distance" contains the maximum value, as opposed to just returning the value.

ie. from:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [pid] => 1
        [type] => lj
        [distance] => 211849216
        [maxspeed] => 277598944
        ...
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [pid] => 1
        [type] => lj
        [distance] => 230286752
        [maxspeed] => 289118816
        ...
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [pid] => 1
        [type] => lj
        [distance] => 230840928
        [maxspeed] => 298438336
        ...
    )
...
```

I wish to get `[2]`:

```
(
    [pid] => 1
    [type] => lj
    [distance] => 230840928
    [maxspeed] => 298438336
    ...
)
```

I've been able to get the max value with the following:

```
function max_dist($a) {
    return $a["distance"];
}
$jump = max(array_map("max_dist", $jumps)));
```

But unlike how elegantly simple it is with JS/underscore:

```
var jump=_.max(jumps,function(o){
    return +o.distance;
});
```

it only returns the max distance value.

I have to just be missing something simple in PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function max_dist($array) {
    $maxIndex = 0;
    $index = 0;
    $maxValue = $array[0]['distance'];
    foreach( $array as $i){
        if($i['distance'] > $maxValue){
            $maxValue = $i['distance'];
            $maxIndex = $index;
        }
    $index++;
    }
    return $array[$maxIndex];
}
$jump = max(array_map("max_dist", $jumps)));
```

Comment: Not at all elegant/simple like it is in JS but I guess it gets the job done just fine. Thanks for the quick response sir!

Comment: This code is meant to be added to the `function max_dist($array) ` but I had a problem editing this on mobile :D